# how to set and get the cookie in nodejs http use jwt without express?

Tags: node.js, http, cookies, jwt, token

when I set the cookie in this way:
res.writeHead(200, {
'Set-Cookie': `access-token=${token}`,
})
how can I get the cookie in another request ?

Comment: If the cookie was set correctly, and the client is sending it back there will be a `cookie` header in the request.

Answer (score 0):

If the cookie was set, then you should be able to get the cookie in the request header.

```
console.log(request.cookies);
```